# How do I implement JSONP for auto-suggest?

Tags: jsonp, autosuggest

I need to implement a cross domain auto-suggest functionality where the results from one domain, say www.example1.com, must be retrieved and sent to another domain, say www.example2.com, from where the actual request is happening. 
JSONP seems to be a popular answer to such cross domain problems. 
The server side programming language is Java.
If anyone has any pointers on the server side changes required, and how the results must be structured to be sent back to the other domain, it would be greatly appreciated.